# ANA non-stop flight from BOM to NRT

Tags: air-travel, technical-stops

The non-stop flight from BOM to NRT is indeed non-stop. However the return flight, which is designated non-stop too, stops for a while at Fukuoka. Is this some kind of technical stop?

Comment: Nitpick: TOK is apparently the tiny village of [Torokina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torokina) on Bougainville Island, Papua New Guinea.  It's not clear that it has an airport, much less nonstop flights to Bombay.  The "airport" code for Tokyo is TYO, though since it has multiple airports that could be ambiguous; I am guessing you want Narita (NRT).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm presuming you are referring to NH943 from Tokyo Narita (NRT) to Mumbai (BOM).

During the winter months this flight does indeed make a technical stop at Fukuoka on the NRT-BOM leg, which is required due to the combination of the distance of the flight, the headwinds normally experienced during winter in that direction, and the fact that ANA chooses to use a 737 to fly this route.

The return trip (BOM-NRT, NH944) does not require a stop due as the winds are beneficial in that direction which means that the aircraft has the range to make it in one hop.

Comment: 10 hour flight - hrmm - that must be a BBJ version because a normal 737 doesn't have that much range.

Comment: I believe it was an all-business-class config when it first started (similar to what SQ used to run from Singapore to LAX/JFK with their all-business A350's), however it now has about a dozen economy seats in it too.

Comment: Just for future readers: NH943 no longer exists -- it's been replaced by NH829 which is flown by a B788.  No more tech stop!